# ubuntu 20.04 dual booting with windows 10(pre-installed) shows ACPI BIOS error

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, hp, bios, acpi

I am working on a fresh hp system.it has genuine windows pre-installed. While i am trying to make  it dual boot with ubuntu 20.04 LTS it shows some error.Please not all the general requirements for ubuntu 20.04 is satisfied in my sytem.here iam attaching screenshot of error(ACPI BIOS ERROR).after showing this error installation process stuck there.[error scrren shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t123.jpg)

Comment: What model is your HP?  Have you checked for any firmware updates to the system (both motherboard and SSD)?  If new, maybe try the 5.8 kernel in the hwe package or 20.10.

Comment: HP Laptop 15s-du3047TX(i5 11 th gen purchased last week).also tried for "ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64" shows same kind of errors

Comment: Actually all this happened while "Try ubuntu without install" option(if all works fine then only planned to install that's why didn't go for a direct install)